# Loading model partially according to the saved state

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to display only a few elements in the state of the viewer saved by the user without having to render the entire model. Is there a way to load certain parts of the model according to the viewer state so that it does not require rendering the whole model while initializing the viewer?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no API available for loading model partially currently. So, you have two options to archive this:

1. Load full model, then show/hide elements after all geometries are loaded.
2. Split your model into several individual model files and translate separately. Afterward, load/unload models according to your need. Here is a blog showing how to do it in the Viewer: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/aggregate-multi-models-sequence-forge-viewer

Hope it helps.